# Laravel 5.2 - Change Data Format get from Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have a model like this-

```
$feature_project = FeatureProject::select('feature_id')
                       ->where('project_id', $project->id)
                       ->get();
```

And if I return it, I am getting a output like this-

```
[
  {
    "feature_id": 2
  },
  {
    "feature_id": 4
  },
  {
    "feature_id": 9
  }
]
```

But I want t output like this-

```
[2,4,9]
```

So I need to convert the output.

But I am not finding a way without using for-each loop (make a temp array, push all elements to that array from current array with a for-each loop).

But I think there is more smart way than that in Laravel to do that.

I think Laravel Collection is used for this purpose.

Comment: Did you try PHP json_decode()? I think that should convert this `[{"feature_id":2},{"feature_id":4},{"feature_id":9}]` to this `[2,4,9]`

Comment: @Michel Eloquent returns a collection. It's encoded to json only in the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `pluck()` method on the query builder.

```
$feature_project = FeatureProject::select('feature_id')
                                        ->where('project_id', $project->id)
                                        ->pluck('feature_id'); // [2,4,9]
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_lists

Alternatively, you can use PHP's `array_column()` function for raw arrays.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: ->pluck('feature_id');  is better than any other option for this, but lists is also a good answer. But lists() will be depricated from laravel 5.3, so pluck is best answer

Comment: @AbrarJahin Thanks for the info, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel's collections, you can call a method called Flatten, which flattens a multi-dimensional collection into a single dimension.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-flatten

```
$collection = collect(['name' => 'taylor', 'languages' => ['php', 'javascript']]);

$flattened = $collection->flatten();

$flattened->all();

// ['taylor', 'php', 'javascript'];
```

With a fairly  flat object, it should return just the values.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pluck()`:

```
$feature_project = FeatureProject::where('project_id', $project->id)->pluck('feature_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way also will be helpful in some cases.
We can run `raw` queries inside `select` function.
Here is an example:

```
$feature_project = FeatureProject::select(DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT("feature_id")))
                   ->where('project_id', $project->id)
                   ->get();
```

In `DB::raw` we can run mysql query with function and case same as mysql query.

Comment: May I know why it is wrong? I am already using this type of queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lists()` and `toArray()` :

```
$feature_project=FeatureProject::where('project_id', $project->id)->lists('id')->toArray();
```

Hope this helps.